# Who are the Vishnu Dutas?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, puranas, bhagavata-purana

There is the mention of Vishnu Dutas in the story of Ajamila mentioned in the Srimad Bhagavatam, Are there any other associated stories/information about them in other scriptures?

https://www.quora.com/Who-are-Vishnu-Dutas-How-powerful-are-they

In one of the answer, there is a mention of Nand-Sunand, Who is Nand-Sunand? What scriptures emntion about him? Who are some other Vishnu Dutas?